# Efficiently saving a vector graphic with RegionPlot and labels

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format

I would like to save an image as a vector graphic (.pdf), so that when I zoom in, the lines and labels remain crisp. However, the image I am saving also contains components that are generated by RegionPlot. When I save these as vector graphics, the file sizes are massive, hundreds of times larger than the vector graphics not including components generated by RegionPlot.

Is there a way to save a plot so that the labels and lines on the plot are vector graphics, but shaded regions are not? An example of the image I am trying to save is below.

[image]

Edit: Code used to produce this graphic is below:

```
linelegs[label_, legs_, pos_, cols_] := 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[
    Table[Text[
      Style[legs[[i]], 14, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]], {i, 1, 
      Length[legs]}], 
    LegendLabel -> 
     Text[Style[label, 14, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]], 
    LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3], 14}, 
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", cols}], pos]
frameStyle[xlabel_, ylabel_, fsize_: 14] := {Axes -> None, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  FrameLabel -> {{Text[
      Style[ylabel, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", fsize]], 
     Text[Style["", fsize]]}, {Text[
      Style[xlabel, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", fsize]], 
     Text[Style["", fsize]]}}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", fsize}}
text[x0_, y0_, txt_, color_] := 
 Graphics[Text[
   Style[txt, color, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 14], {x0, y0}]]
Cell[StyleData["Print"], FontSize -> 36];
PH1 = ImplicitRegion[
   y >= 0 && y <= x (x + 2) && y >= x (x - 2) && x >= 0, {x, y}];
eps = 0.1;
Plasmon1 = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   x >= 0.403205 && x <= 1.25 && 
    y >= Sqrt[((16 \[Pi])/(3 \[Pi]^2)^(4/3) + 
        eps) + (12/5 - eps/(0.403205)^2) x^2] && 
    y <= Sqrt[((16 \[Pi])/(3 \[Pi]^2)^(4/3) - 
        eps) + (12/5 + eps/(0.403205)^2) x^2], {x, y}];
Regions1 = 
  RegionPlot[{PH1, Plasmon1}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, LightRed}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"q/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(F\)]\)", 
     "\[Omega]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(F\)]\)"}, PlotPoints -> 5];

PHLines1 = 
  Plot[{x (x - 2), x (x + 2)}, {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue}];
PlasmonLines11 = 
  Plot[{Sqrt[(16 \[Pi])/(3 \[Pi]^2)^(4/3) + 12/5 x^2]}, {x, 0, 
    0.403205}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red}];
PlasmonLines21 = 
  Plot[{Sqrt[(16 \[Pi])/(3 \[Pi]^2)^(4/3) + 12/5 x^2]}, {x, 0.403205, 
    1.25}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];
figure = Show[{Regions1, PHLines1, PlasmonLines11, PlasmonLines21}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, frameStyle["q", "\[Omega]", 50], 
  FrameTicks -> {{{None}, None}, {{None}, None}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you please post the code used to generate the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a work-around that is acceptable for my images. If Filling->Axis is used instead of RegionPlot, the image is around a factor of 100 smaller.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Use at end of your code the Export Function on figure like this you will find it in your home directory saved in PDF format**

```
Export["plot.pdf", figure]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The issue I am having is related to the file size of such objects. When I export a file as a .pdf without the RegionPlot, the file size is ~10 KB (small, acceptable). When the file includes the regions, the size is ~10 MB. This image size is much too large for my purposes, and causes very long loading times for the documents that contain them. I am wondering if there is a way to save the lines and text as vector graphics, but the regions as something not so memory-intensive.